# File: file:/C:/Python/HDFS/program1/mapper.py is not readable

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am getting below error while executing starting Hadoop job

File: file:/C:/Python/HDFS/program1/mapper.py is not readable.

Using below command

```
hadoop jar C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\tools\lib\hadoop-streaming-3.2.0.jar -file C:/Python/HDFS/program1/mapper.py -file C:/Python/HDFS/program1/reducer.py -mapper "python mapper.py" -reducer "python reducer.py" -input /sample/input_word.txt -output /sample/owc1.txt
```

Here is my mapper.py file content

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        print ("%s\t%s" % (word, 1))
```

And reducer.py content as below

```
import sys
import collections

counter = collections.Counter()

for line in sys.stdin:
    word, count = line.strip().split("\t", 1)

    counter[word] += int(count)

for x in counter.most_common(9999):
    print(x[0],"\t",x[1])
```

I am using the below environment:

Java Version : java version "1.8.0_291"
Hadoop Version: Hadoop 3.2.0
and Windows 10

Comment: Just a guess since I can't test right now—maybe Hadoop expects the `-file` argument to be a path in HDFS, not on your local filesystem? Assuming the root of your HDFS is stored at `C:/Python/HDFS`, you might try just giving `-file /program1/reducer.py` and `file /program1/mapper.py`.

Comment: @fakedad tried the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the version of your hadoop by an oldest version, i had a version 3.2.4 and I've had the same error when I tried to execute the hadoop job command, until I change it by version 2.10.2 the problem was solved.